# Pass array as reference in PHP 5.2.13?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

How can I fix this method to accept reference passing?

It throws **`Fatal error:`**`Only variables can be passed by reference`.

```
/**
 * Set a value "deep within" an associative array.
 *
 * @param array $array_ - Target array to set value on.
 * @param mixed $value - A value to set.
 * @param string $keyPath - Like 'campaign.pushMessages.sendDate'.
 */
private function setValueForKeyPath(&$array, $value, $keyPath)
{
    $keys = explode(".", $keyPath, 2); // Like [ 'campaign', 'pushMessages.sendDate' ]

    // If keys is a leaf key...
    $isLeaf = (count($keys) == 1);
    if ($isLeaf)
    {
        // ...simply set the value.
        $array[$keys[0]] = $value;
    }

    else
    {
        // ...or set a sub-array as value.
        $this->setValueForKeyPath($array[$keys[0]], $value, $keys[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: function code is OK. Error surely is in the function call. What you pass as $array argument?

Comment: the problem is probably not the function, but rather the *outer* function call. If you supply an array directly (e.g. `$obj->setValueForKeyPath(array(....`) you'll get this error.

Comment: I pass in a "foreign" array received in the constructor that uses this function. Should I... ...make variable from that as well?

Comment: Hmm... it works well with dummy array defined just above the function call.

Comment: Aw, passed in a non-array. Only error message mislead me owards wrong directions.